# Android intent problem: why arent these 2 variables equal?

Tags: android, android-intent

Im going a little crazy with this. In my app, i take a string which represents a bus stop, and then have an algorithm that matches it and displays its schedule. I needed to make that window an activity instead of a dialog and am using intents. Heres my code to send the intent:

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, StopDialogActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("stop name", stopName);
                context.startActivity(intent);
```

and heres my code to retrieve the string (in my onCreate):

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
departureStopName=extras.getString("stop name");
```

The string displays properly, but it isnt equal to a test string i have which is the same stop. The intent sends an integer over correct, what am i doing wrong with processing strings?

Comment: How are you testing the equality? Make sure when comparing strings to use `testName.equals(stopName)` and not `testName == stopName`. Also it is common practice to use a `static final String` as the key when placing stuff like this in an Intent.  That leaves less room for error on both ends.

Comment: So did that solve the issue, if so I can post an answer.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is then. If they display as the same string, and you are using `.equals()` then it should return true.

Comment: @ Austyn you ended up correct. If you post your comment as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: Alright, I added it. Someone downvoted it, so marking it as correct would help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure when comparing strings to use testName.equals(stopName) and not testName == stopName.

Using `.equals()` uses the equals method in the String class which compares the content.  Using `==` compares the String Objects themselves, which need to be the same object in memory to evaluate to true.

Comment: Why would someone downvote the answer that was specifically mentioned as correct in the comments on the OP. Only reason I added it is because he said he would mark it as correct if I added it as an answer. Read the comments before downvoting next time.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, my problem was while I use .equals() as a test to see if it was coming through okay, i was using == in the part of my code that broke.